# Binding member function to a member variable

Tags: c++, bind

**Precondition:**

Here is a function:

```
typedef std::function<void (int)> Handler;
void g(const Handler& h) {
  h(100);
}
```

, and a class(original version):

```
class A {
 public:
  A(int arg)
    : m(arg) {}

  void f0(int n) {
    std::cout << m + n << std::endl;
  }

  void f() {
    ::g(std::bind(&A::f0, this, std::placeholders::_1));
  }

 private:
  const int m;
};
```

And this will print two lines, '101' and '102':

```
int main() {
  A a1(1);
  a1.f();

  A a2(2);
  a2.f();

  return 0;
}
```

Now I realized `A::f()` will be called very frequently,
so I modified it like this(new version):

```
class A {
 public:
  A(int arg)
    : m(arg),
      handler(std::bind(&A::f0, this, std::placeholders::_1)) {}

  void f0(int n) {
    std::cout << m + n << std::endl;
  }

  void f() {
    ::g(handler);
  }

 private:
  const int m;
  const Handler handler;
};
```

**My Questions:**

Is it safe to bind `this` pointer to a member variable?

Is there no functional difference between two versions?

Can I expect the new version will really gain some performance benefit?
(I suspect my compiler(MSVC) will optimize it by itself,
so I may not need to optimize it by myself).

*PS.: This question corrects and replaces the previous one:
[Binding member function to a local static variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540615/binding-member-function-to-a-local-static-variable)*

Comment: `Is it safe to bind this pointer to a member variable?` Beware the compiler-generated copy constructor and assignment operator. Consider: `A a(42); A b = a;` Here, `b.handler` still refers to `&a`, not `&b`. This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: `Can I expect the new version will really gain some performance benefit?` If you really care, implement it both ways and measure. If you don't measure, then you don't really care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Igor Tandetnik mentioned in comments:

> > Is it safe to bind this pointer to a member variable?
>
> Beware the compiler-generated copy constructor and assignment operator. Consider:
>
> ```
> A a(42); A b = a;
> ```
>
> Here, `b.handler` still refers to `&a`, not `&b`. This may or may not be what you want.

I also don't think the performance benefit deserves dev-time effort to maintain member variables. (*)